# Take elements from items in a list of strings

Tags: python, list, loops

From a given list, take an element from each item to spell a new word.

```
list1=["whiff", "dog", "axe"]
letters=[]
for j in list1:
    for k in j:
        letters.append(k)

answer = letters[4] + letters[6] + letters[9]
```

Is there a way to make it simpler than what I've come up with so far?
Particularly, is there a way to call an element of an item in a list, and
not the entire item itself?  I don't want `list1[0]` for `"whiff"`, I just
want the `"f"` part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is there a way to call an element of an item in a list, and not the entire item itself?

Well, you can chain the subscript operators, with something like this...

```
>>> l = ["whiff", "dog", "axe"]
>>> answer = l[0][4] + l[1][1] + l[2][1]
>>> print answer
fox
```

Comment: Excellent!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Just started programming this semester and didn't know exactly how to articulate my question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1 = ["whiff", "dog", "axe"]

indexes = [4, 6, 9]
getter = itemgetter(*indexes)
print(getter(''.join(list1))) # prints ('f', 'o', 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to have access to a list of all letters in all words you could use:

```
>>> list1=["whiff", "dog", "axe"]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> all_letters = list(chain(*list1))
>>> all_letters
['w', 'h', 'i', 'f', 'f', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'a', 'x', 'e']
>>> answer = all_letters[4] + all_letters[6] + all_letters[9]
```

chain produces a concatenation of all iterables it gets as arguments - strings are iterable, too. I need to call `list` on its result as it only returns an iterator.

Then we have one long list, without the need to write a loop.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no need for `itertools.chain`: `''.join(list1)` do the work.

Comment: you're right. Somehow I ended up using itertools - I like these iterators, but as I do list anyway, it has no advantage here.